# unable to iterate through loop in python

Tags: python, loops

i have a sql query which basically retrieves coin names and submits an order for each coin.
However, it only submits an order on one coin and fails to loop through the rest, not sure why thats happening .

```
import sys

**
import pandas as pd


postgreSQL_select_Query = "SELECT base,quote FROM instrument_static where exchange='ftx'"

cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
row=([y for y in cursor.fetchall()])

for i in row:
   base=i[0]
   quote=i[1]
   portfolioItems = [
       {
           'exchange': 'ftx',
           'base': base,
           'quote': quote,
           'amount': 0.01,
       },

   ]


   def init():

       username = us
       password = passwordVal
       initialise(clientId, clientSecret, us, password)


if __name__ == "__main__":
       init()
       result = construct_portfolio_with_params(us, portname, portfolioItems)
       print(result)
```

Comment: Do you want `portfolioItems` to be a list containing a dictionary for each row? Right now it is overwriting each time in the loop and will contain a single dictionary. You are also creating the `init` function multiple times.

Comment: Do you want portfolioItems to be a list containing a dictionary for each row? YES how do i do that?

Comment: seems like u have create a set of dict , can you try replace `row=([y for y in cursor.fetchall()])` by `row=[[y for y in cursor.fetchall()]]` ? to create a list of dict  instead of  set of dict , i use `set()` rarly maybe i'm wrong

Comment: Your code is showing only a loop where it constantly creates a variable portfolioItems, but it gets reset at each iteration of the loop and it doesn't do anything with it, like submitting an order or returning a value. I think your list should be initialized before the loop and at each iteration a new dictionary is appended to it, so after finishing the loop, you get a list with dictionaries as items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `portfolioItems` prior to the loop, and then you can add to it. Try replacing this snippet of code:

```
...
row=([y for y in cursor.fetchall()])

portfolioItems = []

for i in row:
   base=i[0]
   quote=i[1]
   portfolioItems.append(
       {
           'exchange': 'ftx',
           'base': base,
           'quote': quote,
           'amount': 0.01,
       }

   )
...
```